# Setting up mercurial repository with Android Studio, .gitignore file

Tags: android, mercurial, android-studio-2.3

I've just attempted to create a new mercurial repository using Android Studio (v2.3.2)

I went through the menu option VCS->Import into Version Control->Create Mercurial Repository

The 1st time I did this I was careless and accepted the default folder location for the repo which turned out to be the parent dir of my new project, thus overwriting an existing repo I had there (hopefully I can restore from backup)

The 2nd time I correctly specified the new project dir and I saw that an `.hg` dir was created in there as expected. Confusingly though, it also created a `.gitignore` file in the project dir as well.

Does mercurial attempt to read `.gitignore` files or is this a bug in Android Studio?

Running `hg add -n` seems to suggest it isn't reading the `.gitignore` file

I would have expected Android Studio to create an `.hgignore` file instead?

Is the expectation you have to either rename the `.gitignore` file to `.hgignore` and add the `syntax: glob` line at the top or are you supposed to manually create your own `.hgignore` file?

I assume it isn't a good idea to simply add all files?

Comment: It's a bug in Angroid Studio. Mercurial uses .hgignore, which has a different format.

Comment: spun the problem round and attempted to create a git repo, rather than a mercurial repo - guess what? no .gitignore file at all with this approach.. laughable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't read a .gitignore file or treat it specially in any way.

However you can probably convert it by adding the `syntax: glob` directive at the top and renaming - as you suggest yourself